Nextjs handling "window is not defined" without useEffect() or dynamic imports?
So in nextjs, you get a window is not defined error because of SSR (ie. window is not defined in the server environment).
The typical way to get around this is to use a dynamic import or place what you need inside a useEffect() hook. I don't see how this can work with my current code though. Currently I initialize firebase functions in this helper:
export const functions = (() => {
    const functions = getFunctions(!getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp());
    if (window?.location?.hostname === "localhost") {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, '127.0.0.1', 5001)
    }
    return functions
})()

This connects the firebase functions emulator only if the domain is localhost. Things would get really messy if I were to initialize firebase functions in a useEffect() hook everywhere, and afaik I can't do dynamic imports because it's just for components.
So my question is, how could I defer checking what the hostname is until it is loaded client side? Or is there another way around this?

I ended up using a custom hook with useEffect(). It actually isn't so messy after all.
export const functions =  getFunctions(app);

export const useEmulator = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (window?.location?.hostname === "localhost") {
            connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, '127.0.0.1', 5001)
        }
    }, [])
}

